# DateTimePicker shows ontop of input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using the "Timepicker Addon for jQuery UI Datepicker". It is working for what I need and a pretty slick addon, but I am having a problem. I have a page full of inputs and with the ones close the top and it seems to get confused on it's own height. For some reason it seems think it is shorter than it actually is. This causes the datetimepicker to actually sit on top of the input so to speak and cover it so you can't see what it is doing.

I did do some testing and found that when I made the time picking part on the bottom "display: none" it fit on the page and lined up just right. Not really sure what to do. Something as simple as always having it pop up on the bottom would solve it.

[image]

Comment: can you post your Fiddle or Datepicker Code with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can do that shift your date picker on top

```
padding-bottom: 20px;//padding start from bottom side
```

Comment: I tried to do it with CSS. However the problem is that the reason it is ontop of the input box is that it is pushed right up against the top of the page. So in this case padding the bottom wouldn't do anything. The popup for the datetimepicker would need to be below the input not above.

Comment: This fiddle shows what I am talking about with the input being ontop of the input itself.
http://jsfiddle.net/2tywpfn1/

Comment: Please adjust your margin-top of your datepicker  if you want on top of input field

Comment: I will give it a try and see what it does

Comment: I took a look at your fiddle and the issue is that I don't have control over where the input is on the page. I set the margin-top just to locate the input in an area of the page where it would cause the issue. The problem itself seems to do with the fact that the DateTimePicker is taller than the date picker and there doesn't seems to be away to account for that.